# Cakephp : Basecamp XML to Array to View

Tags: cakephp, simplexml, basecamp

I've been working on Basecamp API integration and I find it too sluggish using Cakephp's HttpSocket, Xml loader using Set::reverse. Anyone have tried working similar?

What my code does is provide the API token as required by Basecamp parsed Xml into array and return parsed XML to calling procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your qestion right, but maybe the [XML helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1473/XML) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Basically, Basecamp returns XML data, and I parsed them into array then render it to view.